# Need to add data to table only if the latest data (latest based highest date) for the record does not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table EMPLOYEE with the following fields:

```
ENROLL_DATE EMP ID  EMP_NAME   DEPT   SWITCH
01-20-2001   123      ABC       D1      N
01-20-2012   123      ABC       D2      N
10-12-2016   123      RST       D2      N
02-10-2017   123      RST       D3      N
02-10-2017   456      TYU       D2      N
```

I have another table EMPLOYE_CUR

```
 ENROLL_DATE EMP ID  EMP_NAME   DEPT   SWITCH
 02-23-2017   123      PQR       D4      N
 02-23-2017   456      TYU       D2      Y
```

I need to insert records into table EMPLOYEE only if its a new record (New being record is changed for EMP_ID or EMP_NAME or DEPT, even if SWITCH is changed we wont insert that record)
We will be comparing the reocrd for the emp_ID for hisgest ENROLL_DATE. So if the record is changed based on the latest record for the emp_ID in table EMPLOYEE then only we will be inserting that record.
So in above case the records which need to be inserted are:

```
 ENROLL_DATE EMP ID  EMP_NAME   DEPT   SWITCH
 02-23-2017   123      PQR       D4      N
```

So employee table will now have:

```
 ENROLL_DATE EMP ID  EMP_NAME   DEPT   SWITCH
 01-20-2001   123      ABC       D1      N
 01-20-2012   123      ABC       D2      N
 10-12-2016   123      RST       D2      N
 02-10-2017   123      RST       D3      N
 02-19-2017   123      RST       D4      Y
 02-23-2017   123      PQR       D4      N
```

I was trying to do this using cursor getting all the records form EMPLOYEE table with highest Enroll_date and then thinking to compare that with EMPLOYEE_CUR table, but could not figure out how to do.

Can anyone help me with the query here?

Thanks!

Comment: *changed for EMP_ID* is probably too much. New EMP_ID is simple a new employee, you have no chance with your table to recognise chnage of EMP_ID (This would require additional column PREVIOUS_EMP_ID)

Comment: Please look at your `EMPLOYEE_CUR` table, last two rows. Imagine the `EMP_NAME` was `PQR` in both (instead of changing from `RST` to `PQR`). In that case, would you still insert both rows? If not, which one would you insert - only the earlier one? (That would be the most logically consistent answer)

Comment: And, in any case, do NOT do this in a PL/SQL procedure; whatever the correct and complete requirement is, you can do it all in plain SQL, with much greater efficiency and maintainability.

Comment: Yep, @mathguy I understand it the same way, the first record would represent the change, the second should be ignored...

Comment: @mathguy- in case both emp_name in EMPLOYEE_CUR is PQR, then we will be inserting only 1 row and that should be the 1st encountered one with date (02-19-2017) because it means EMP_NAME changed from RST to PQR on 02-19-2017 date.

Also, can you please tell me how it can be written in plsql?

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a simplified solution, that should give you  advice how to handle your possible special cases.

Note that I assume that the common history is identical in both tables and that a
new employee will be created in both tables.

If this is not true you mast refine the query to address it.

The solution has two parts:

1) **filter** idle records in `EMPLOYE_CUR` that corresponds to **no change** (e.g. only SWITCH changed) - use [analytical functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) to trace the last values

2) select the real change records **that have ENROLL_DATE higher that the MAX(ENROLL_DATE) from table `EMPLOYEE`**

(The last step INSERT  is not considered as obvious.) - see below

**STEP 1**

```
with history as (
select ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT,SWITCH,
LAG(EMP_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ENROLL_DATE) PREV_EMP_NAME,
LAG(DEPT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ENROLL_DATE) PREV_DEPT
from EMPLOYE_CUR)
select 
  ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT, SWITCH,
  case when EMP_NAME != PREV_EMP_NAME or DEPT != PREV_DEPT then 'Y' end is_changed
from history;

ENROLL_DATE             EMP_ID EMP_NAME   DEPT       SWITCH     IS_CHANGED
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
20.01.2001 00:00:00        123 ABC        D1         N                     
20.01.2012 00:00:00        123 ABC        D2         N          Y          
12.10.2016 00:00:00        123 RST        D2         N          Y          
10.02.2017 00:00:00        123 RST        D3         N          Y          
17.02.2017 00:00:00        123 RST        D3         Y                     
19.02.2017 00:00:00        123 RST        D4         Y          Y          
23.02.2017 00:00:00        123 PQR        D4         N          Y
```

**STEP 2**

```
with history as (
select ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT,SWITCH,
LAG(EMP_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ENROLL_DATE) PREV_EMP_NAME,
LAG(DEPT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ENROLL_DATE) PREV_DEPT
from EMPLOYE_CUR),
clean_history as (
select 
  ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT, SWITCH,
  case when EMP_NAME != PREV_EMP_NAME or DEPT != PREV_DEPT then 'Y' end is_changed
from history)
select clean_history.ENROLL_DATE, clean_history.EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT, SWITCH from clean_history 
join (select EMP_ID, max(ENROLL_DATE) ENROLL_DATE from  EMPLOYEE group by EMP_ID) e
on clean_history.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID and clean_history.ENROLL_DATE > e.ENROLL_DATE
where is_changed = 'Y';


ENROLL_DATE             EMP_ID EMP_NAME   DEPT       SWITCH   
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
19.02.2017 00:00:00        123 RST        D4         Y          
23.02.2017 00:00:00        123 PQR        D4         N
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below query and its working fine. Not sure if i covered all scenarios:

```
INSERT into EMPLOYEE(ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT, SWITCH)
SELECT ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT, SWITCH FROM EMPLOYEE_CUR
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A WHERE A.EMP_ID = EMPLOYEE_CUR.EMP_ID
    AND A.EMP_NAME = EMPLOYEE_CUR.EMP_NAME
    AND DEPT= EMPLOYEE_CUR.DEPT
    AND A.Enroll_date in (SELECT MAX(enroll_date) over ( partition by emp_id) as max_date from employee b where a.emp_id=b.emp_id));
```

Can someone comment if it looks correct?

Comment: It doesn't seem correct in the following case: for a given `EMP_ID`, the most current values of `EMPN_NAME` and `DEPT`  in `EMPLOYEE_CUR` are the same as the most recent values in `EMPLOYEES` - but in fact there HAVE been changes. For example: since the last update to `EMPLOYEES`, the employee has changed departments once, and then they returned to the original department. Your query will miss that. And, on the other hand, in the example in my Comment to your question, it will pick up two rows from `EMPLOYEE_CUR` even if there is no change **between those two rows**.

Comment: And you don't seem to filter out "change rows" (rows in `EMPLOYEE_CUR`) that have a date **older than** the most recent date (for that employee) in `EMPLOYEES`. I assume only such records should be considered for INSERT in the first place, right?

Comment: @mathguy can you put example of what you are saying as i am unable to understand what you mean.

Comment: Suppose the most current row in `EMPLOYEE` is `123-PQR-D4`. In `EMPLOYEE_CUR` you have two rows with a later date than the most recent date in `EMPLOYEE`, with the values `123-PQR-D8` and later `123-PQR-D4`.  The first of these two rows will satisfy your conditions and will be inserted, but the second will NOT be inserted because it doesn't show a change from the `EMPLOYEES` table. Whether the second row is inserted or not **SHOULD** depend on the first inserted row (from `EMPLOYEE_CUR`), but in your query it doesn't - it only depends on the original state of the `EMPLOYEES` table.

Comment: You **could** do it "your way" if you only inserted one row at a time (but then you would need even more logic to add them "in order"), but only if you commit after every single insert. This would, indeed, require PL/SQL and it would be exceptionally inefficient. I'll work on a pure SQL solution if I can find some time this afternoon.

Comment: in EMPLOYEE_CUR table EMP_ID is primary key. I think that wont cause that situation itself.

Just for information EMPLOYEE table has ENROLL_DATE, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME,  and dept as PK

Comment: Err.. in your sample data, EMPLOYEE_CUR has two rows for ID=123, is that a typo? How can you have duplicate values in a PK?

Comment: By the way, I was just working on this problem, and EMP_ID was definitely not a PK in my test data, so it's good I saw this before I got too far.

Comment: Hi Mathguy, Did you come up with a solution? I am editing that record to have only 1 record as emp_id is PK.